# How to take a number from regular expression and pass it to match certain text?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regular expression `[A-Za-z0-9!@#$?]+=(\d+)<<` and I have to match any text after `<<` with length of the number given in the first capturing group ? Can you please help me, appreciate it :)

Comment: A regex is the wrong tool for that.

Comment: Regex alone won't be suffice. You will need to also write some code. Can you share your current code/effort?

Comment: Could you provide examples? I cannot understand in detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this RegEx "(\d+)<<(\d+)"  you can use your capture groups 1 and 2 for your program logic.  Here is an example:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class MainApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] searchMe = {"3<<123", "2<<123", "4<<1234", "4<<123"};  
    //indexes 0 and 2 should pass the test 

    String regExPattern = "(\\d+)<<(\\d+)";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile( regExPattern );

    for(String x : searchMe){
            Matcher m = p.matcher( x );
            boolean b = m.matches();

            if(b)
            {
                int numLen = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
                String group2 = m.group(2);
                if(group2.length()  == numLen ){
                    System.out.println(x);
                }
            }



            }
    }

    }
```

My console prints out:

```
3<<123
4<<1234
```

Comment: Sorry, previous RegEx was for only digits.  Use this one for digits and letters:  (\d+)<<(\d+|\w+\s*)+

Hopefully this gets you closer to a solution!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Patrick! Please note that you can always [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55672957/edit) your answer/question to add more information or fix a mistake.